# How to set multiple elements in wpf data binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to highlight Datagridcells using IMultiValueConverter.
I highlight  background of Datagrid based on text box input text.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtPartDescription/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtPartNumber"/>
```

I also want add txtPartNumber to `Models:SearchOperations.SearchTerm="{Binding ElementName=txtPartDescription,Path=Text}"`

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"                        
          Models:SearchOperations.SearchTerm="{Binding ElementName=txtPartDescription,Path=Text}"
          CellStyle="{StaticResource DefaultCell}" 
          x:Name="productDataGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource productViewSource},IsAsync=True}"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
```

How can I bind multiple Elements to `Models:SearchOperations.SearchTerm="{Binding ElementName=txtPartDescription,Path=Text}"`?

Newly Added Code

```
public class SearchTermConverter:IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var stringValue = values[0] == null ? string.Empty : values[0].ToString();
        
        var searchTerm = values[1] as string;
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue) &&
            stringValue.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower());
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, Object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    
    }

    
}



public static class SearchOperations
{
    public static string GetSearchTerm(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(SearchTermProperty);
    
    }
    public static void SetSearchTerm(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    { 
    obj.SetValue(SearchTermProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchTermProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SearchTerm", typeof(string), typeof(SearchOperations),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits)); 
    public static bool GetIsMatch(DependencyObject obj) 
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsMatchProperty);
    
    }
    public static void SetIsMatch(DependencyObject obj, bool value) 
    {

        obj.SetValue(IsMatchProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMatchProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMatch", typeof(bool),
            typeof(SearchOperations), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

}
```

I have tried nothing yet and I don't know how to approach the problem.

Comment: you could just use multible datatriggers on the cell template to achive the highlighting based on different properties

Comment: @DenisSchaf, Please explain

Comment: i suggest you to post a minimal code to reproduce the problem...most of helpers have no time to recreate a projet to analyse your problem

Comment: It is hard to answer your question without knowing the type of th`Models:SearchOperations.SearchTerm` and how it is consumed. You will probably need to change it to support an collection of strings, or some other type. After that, as you correctly stated, you will need to write a `IMultiValueConverter`  that makes (for instance) an array from individual values.